Plot time (hours, minutes, seconds) along y axis
I would like to plot time (in hours, minutes, seconds) on the ordinate and date on the abscissa, much as in this answer, but I don't want to convert the abscissa values to a single unit (e.g., seconds), as in the linked answer.  I'd like large ticks marking hours, and smaller ticks marking every 15 minutes (say), and possibly individual ticks for seconds.
I can do this by brute force, creating special ticks, reading the individual components of the TimeObject values and such, but I thought there might be an elegant Option or whole graphing function that does this automatically.  I have found none.
Here is sample data:
myData = {{DateObject[{2020, 5, 24}],TimeObject[{1,6,20}]},
          {DateObject[{2020, 5, 25}],TimeObject[{0,53,11}]},
          {DateObject[{2020, 5, 26}],TimeObject[{0,49,19}]}};

DatelistPlot[myData]

